# Flutter Textfield with prefix and hint

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want to achieve textfield with always show prefix even without focus, prefix must be align with the hint. Customize using bordered container doesn't have flying hint animation, so built-in textfield is the only choice.

Expectation:
[image]

I tried to set prefix, prefixIcon, and prefixText, but nothing work as expectation, that built-in prefix cannot be align with the hint. I also tried to set prefix constraint to zero but nothing work. Do you have any idea ?

Result:

[image]

Code snippet:

```dart
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16).r,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)).r,
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: 1,
                    color: Color(0xFFDADADA),
                  ),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    labelText: 'Terendah',
                    alignLabelWithHint: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    isDense: true,
                    prefixIconConstraints:
                        const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32, minHeight: 0).r,
                    prefixIcon: SizedBox(
                      child: Text('Rp'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: TextEditingController(text: ''),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: actually you can make a custom of textfield, wrap Rp icon and the textfield part in a container, after that you can wrap it with sizebox and put the border, and you should achieve something like that

Comment: Customize textfield doesn't have flying hint animation, so built-in textfield is the only choice.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Terendah",
      prefix: Text("Rp"),
       ),
 )
```

and you will get result something like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

you can remove the border from the textfield and give it a border with a container around it like this:

```
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Terendah",
                      prefix: Text("Rp"),
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

and the result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: The label not inside the border

Comment: @omega_mi check the answer now i updated it.

Comment: Thats good but i need always show prefix, yours is shown only when on focus.

Comment: it is shown check it

Comment: Already check it, i need always show prefix even without focus. Yours only show when in focus.

Comment: checkout the two screenshots i have attached one is of focus state and one is unfocus state in both the prefix is shown

Comment: The hint must be inside the border. And for the 2nd screenshot it's not always show prefix, because need to be focus to display the prefix. What i want to achieve is always show prefix even without any focus and the hint must be inside the border.